# cross product between DatetimeIndex and int64

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas `DatetimeIndex` object `dt` of length 10k and a list of 10 integers `code`. I want to create a dataframe of the column cross product (Cartesian product) of the two objects.

How can I do it ?

```
dt = DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-22 09:00:00', '2019-01-22 09:15:00',
               '2019-02-07 00:15:00', '2019-02-07 00:30:00',
               '2019-02-07 00:45:00', '2019-02-07 01:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=11137, freq=None)

code = [1000,1001]
```

I wand the DataFrame to be

```
df
                 datetime        code
        0  '2019-02-07 00:15:00', 1000
        1  '2019-02-07 00:15:00', 1001
        2  '2019-02-07 00:30:00', 1000
               ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from  itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame(product(dt, code), columns=['datetime','code'])
#oldier pandas versions
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(dt, code)), columns=['datetime','code'])
print (df)

              datetime  code
0  2019-01-22 09:00:00  1000
1  2019-01-22 09:00:00  1001
2  2019-01-22 09:15:00  1000
3  2019-01-22 09:15:00  1001
4  2019-02-07 00:15:00  1000
5  2019-02-07 00:15:00  1001
6  2019-02-07 00:30:00  1000
7  2019-02-07 00:30:00  1001
8  2019-02-07 00:45:00  1000
9  2019-02-07 00:45:00  1001
10 2019-02-07 01:00:00  1000
11 2019-02-07 01:00:00  1001
```